# Can we increase the google map static URL character length to upto fifty thousand characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-static-api

Actually i am using Google static map API in Nodejs to get satellite image of Multi geometry path (3) and markers with custom style (400), but the length of created URL is beyond 45000 characters, so could you help me to find any other service which can allow this much URL length or any other implementation technique to get map satellite image with path and markers in such a big count of path and markers.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#url-size-restriction),

> Maps Static API URLs are restricted to 8192 characters in size.

And to answer your question, there's currently no way to increase this character limit.

But, we do have an [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124504231) for this in our Google Issue Tracker. However, this entry was marked as a duplicate of another feature request to support KML layers in Static Maps API. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35817020

In the mean time, you might want to consider trying [Maps Javascript API - Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) as this service have an option to [Draw on the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) and allows you to use the [MarkerClusterer library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer) which displays marker clusters instead of a large number of markers on a map. To know more on how marker clustering works, please check out this doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering